# What would cause a router CPU to run 44x slower?

Tags: embedded, clock, router

I have a TP-Link Archer C9 V5 router. After a recent power outage it did not come back up, so I am now trying to see if I can fix it. Occasionally it will still manage to boot and work normally, I was even able to successfully perform a firmware update, but after power cycling it would fail to boot again.

I took it apart and connected to the serial port. On a successful boot the port operates at 115200 baud and spits out all of the normal boot messages. When the boot fails, the console is silent for a while and then starts spewing out garbled data. Or so I thought. I connected the TX pin to my oscilloscope and noticed, that the output is still serial data, but the data rate is now approximately 2625 baud. After changing my serial to USB adapter to this baud rate I was once again able to receive the same boot output as before, but everything was happening slower, and after reaching a certain stage, the router boot-looped.

Given that the data rate is not a standard rate, and that the boot sequence is the same but slower, I have come to a conclusion that the CPU is running approximately 44x times slower than it thinks it is. I don't really know how to even get started on this problem, the one thing I did try was to probe a 25 MHz crystal that is next to the CPU and it was indeed running at 25 MHz. What could be the cause of the problem and how could I debug it?

**Update:**
Following JRE's suggestion below, I resoldered the flash chip and so far it seems to have fixed the problem. I guess the problem was a bad multiplier config that it got from the flash with a bad contact, though I do find it strange that the CFE still seems to have booted normally, albeit slower.

Comment: Internally most SOCs configure clock domains in software during boot up.  If the firmware ROM is corrupt you might have something fail to configure a clock and end up in a random state.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't tell you how to fix the problem, but I think I can explain what is going on.

All versions of the [TP-Link Archer C9](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/TP_Link_Archer_C9) use a 1GHz processor.  You say that there's a 25MHz crystal on it and that it is running at 25MHz.  To get 1GHz out of 25MHz, the processor will be using a phase locked loop to multiply the crystal oscillator output from 25MHz to 1GHz.  That's a factor of 40, which is pretty close to your estimated factor of 44 from the baud rate.

It seems the multiplier sometimes doesn't work or gets set to the wrong multiplication.

The multiplier settings will usually be set during boot up of the processor.  There's some part of the boot code that does that.

1. The boot code may be read incorrectly resulting in an incorrect multiplier setting.
2. There may be a configuration setting stored separately from the firmware.  If the processor encounters an error reading the configuration, it might go into a failsafe mode with a default multiplier setting of 1.
3. The multiplier itself might be defective in some way.

I'd look at the flash, the RAM, and any other EEPROM or non-volatile storage on the board as well as their  connections to the processor. Bad connections or an electrically damaged chip could mangle the settings.

If the multiplier is bad, I don't see any easy way to fix it.  It is internal to the processor, so your only fix would be to replace the processor.

---

You might want to try the [recovery procedure given here](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/TP_Link_Archer_C9#.22Normal.22_Bricked_Router) to reinstall the original firmware in the flash memory of your router.  Following that, it may help to reset it to factory defaults.

Comment: This is very good reasoning, upvoted. I would have added to your list: (3) The stored settings may be corrupt (e.g. fail their stored CRC check), causing the router to use a default safe multiplier of 1.

Comment: Thank you, good eye noticing the 40x ratio. I had thought about problems with the multiplier but didn't make the connection. Anyway, since I've posted this question I've been unable to get the router to boot even once, so I don't think recovery is an option. Also the problem was intermittent, so I don't think it's a firmware issue - a corrupt firmware wouldn't randomly fix itself. I did a firmware update when I got it to boot before, but I don't know if that replaces the bootloader. The question got closed now, I thought it was an interesting enough failure mode but I guess it's too specific.

Comment: So I tried the only hardware fix that seemed feasible - resoldering the TSOP48 flash. I seems to have worked! So far I've done about 10 power cycles and it boots up every time.

Comment: @sasodoma, that's good news but please can you edit it into your question, rather than post it in a hard-to-find comment down here. Thanks.